# Counting paths which cross a box

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\Lambda_{n} = \mathbb{Z}^2 \cap [0,n]^2$. Let $P_n$ be the number of paths which start on the left hand side of this box, $\{0\} \times [0,n]$, finish on the right hand side of this box, $\{n\} \times [0,n]$, and do not visit any vertex twice. The paths can move in any direction.

There are some naive bounds we can obtain by comparing with to easier-to-count paths; for example, by counting paths which go from the bottom left to the top right and only move up or right, we see that $P_n \gtrsim n^{-1/2}4^n$.

Is there anything more we can say about these asymptotics, such as whether $P_n$ grows exponentially or super-exponentially? Or can we determine a limit for $\log(P_n)/n$?

I suspect we might not be able to say much, as this is related to self-avoiding walks which are not that well-understood on $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Comment: Can you clarify "any direction"?

Comment: @Karl I just mean that we are trying to count all self-avoiding paths from the left side of the box to the right side. "Any direction" is to differentiate from similar counting paths questions where, for example, we count paths that only move up and right. In this case our path can travel to any adjacent vertex which has not been previously visited.

Comment: From your first paragraph it isn't clear whether diagonal moves are allowed, for example.

Comment: @Karl Here we are only considering steps taken up, down, left or right.

Comment: An easy upper bound is $4^{n^2}$. I suspect $\log(P_n)/n\to 0$, because drawing a path "usually" requires making more than $O(n)$ choices.